# How can i align timelines from top left align

Tags: flutter

I  used [timelines](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) package .It aligned in center by default. I want to align timelines from top left in Container but that doesnt work. Here is a code i have tried.

[image: Here is Preview]

```
Container(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(
      builder: TimelineTileBuilder.fromStyle(
        contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.basic,
        connectorStyle: ConnectorStyle.solidLine,
        indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle.outlined,
        contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
        ),
        itemCount: 3,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Kindly put whole scaffold code is it inside `Column` or any other widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a option for what you want in Timelines package.

Please give a 'nodePosition' option to 'theme' parameter in tileBuilder.

The 'nodePosition' can have value from 0 to 1.0 double type.
Because default value is a 0.5, timeline will be located at center.

```
theme: TimelineTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            nodePosition: 0,
          ),
```

[image]

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(
        theme: TimelineTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          nodePosition: 0,
        ),
        builder: TimelineTileBuilder.fromStyle(
          contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.basic,
          connectorStyle: ConnectorStyle.solidLine,
          indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle.outlined,
          contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
          ),
          itemCount: 3,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's a limitation of the package that you're using, because it is designed to take all width available.

It looks like it helps a bit to wrap it in an `IntrinsicWidth` like this

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: IntrinsicWidth(
    child: FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(
      builder: TimelineTileBuilder.fromStyle(
        contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.basic,
        connectorStyle: ConnectorStyle.solidLine,
        indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle.outlined,
        contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
        ),
        itemCount: 3,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

But that still leaves some space on the left side for opposite content (or using ContentsAlign.reverse)

Answer (score -1):

If you have used a column widget please add

```dart
crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

Answer (score -1):

You can align widget with below code if your widget taking more width than it's size in the screen

```
 crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

For example,

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children : [
        FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(
          builder: TimelineTileBuilder.fromStyle(
            contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.basic,
            connectorStyle: ConnectorStyle.solidLine,
            indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle.outlined,
            contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
            ),
            itemCount: 3,
          ),
        ),
      ]
    )
```